# autofac injection failing with generic interface & repo

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

I am trying to wire up autofac to a repository that I have create however I keep getting an error "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'DummyController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."

I have defined my interface & repo like

```
public interface IDomainService<T>
{
   ...

}

public class DomainService<T>:IDomainService<T>
{
    protected readonly IDomainService<T> Repository;

    public DomainService(IDomainService<T> repository)
    {
        Repository = repository;
    }

    ....
}
```

I have my custom repo using my interface and domain service

```
 public class FooRepository:IDomainService<FooModel>
 {
     private DataContext db = new DataContext();
     private ILogger log = null;

    public FooRepository(ILogger logger)
    {
        log = logger;

    }

public interface IFoo:IDomainService<FooModel>
{
    ....

}
```

Within my Application_Start configuring autofac

```
builder.RegisterType<FooRepository>().As<IDomainService<FooModel>>().InstancePerDependency();
```

Finally my controller

```
  public class DummyController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IFoo _fooRepository;

    public DummyController(IFoo repository)
    {
        _fooRepository = repository;
    }
```

The site compiles ok however when I try hit my api endpoint I keep getting an error

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'DummyController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

Obviously I have setup something wrong however I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. Can anyone spot what is wrong?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your service as `IFoo` then you need to register it as `IFoo`.

So change your registration to:

```
builder.RegisterType<FooRepository>()
       .As<IFoo>()
       .InstancePerDependency();
```

If you still need to access also with `IDomainService<FooModel>` then you can write:

```
builder.RegisterType<FooRepository>()
       .As<IDomainService<FooModel>>()
       .As<IFoo>()
       .InstancePerDependency();
```

Comment: Thanks @nemesv I get an error when trying the 2nd suggestion The type 'MyApp.Domain.Repository.FooRepository' is not assignable to service 'MyApp.Domain.Interfaces.IFoo'.

Comment: Ok I see now. You need implement the `IFoo` in `FooRepository` with `public class FooRepository: IDomainService<FooModel>, IFoo`. Alternativly you can use `IDomainService<FooModel>` in your controller `public DummyController(IDomainService<FooModel> repository)`